# LWC - Stop the rendering until all the data is fetched

Tags: lightning-web-components

I would like my LWC component to hold off rendering until all the initial data is fetched. I am calling an Apex method to load the initial data imperatively in connectedCallback.

As the call to Apex is asynchronous, the fields are rendered with empty data for a bit which is not a good user experience.

I am using the spinner to be shown until all the data is fetched.

But just wondering whether we can hold off rendering until the initial data is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can't delay rendering of a component. The usual way to take care of this is to show a spinner while loading:

```
<template>
  <lightning-spinner if:true={isLoading}></lightning-spinner>
  <div if:false={isLoading}>
    <!-- rest of your form/components here -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What about when you're using `<lightning-record-edit-form>`, so you don't have control of retrieving the data and setting the spinner? I'm watching the component render field by field and it's ugly...

Comment: Ah... found the answer... use a `onload={handleLoaded}` param in the `<lightning-record-edit-form>`. I set `showSpinner=true` in the initial variables, then set it to false in the `handleLoaded()` handler.

Comment: @PatMcClellan__c We crossed comments. I forgot about the showSpinner thing.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to include your fields in a conditional template, and make this condition true only when all of your initial data is fetched.

you can make the isDataLoaded = true, when your fetch is completed.

Comment: Yes, I generally use this approach, but was temporarily stumped on how to do it when using `lightning-record-edit-form` where the data loads automatically, rather than @wire or imperatively where I can turn the spinner off and make the data visible. The `onload` event in `lightning-record-edit-form` solved the problem.